MySQL 8.0 upgrade/ spike in synch/mutex/innodb/trx_sys_mutex causes application outage
We upgrade mysql from 5.7 to 8.0 on AWS aurora
Problem we are facing is frequent outage of an application.
we observed that there is spike for synch/mutex/innodb/trx_sys_mutex
Performance insights

See my response in similar case https://stackoverflow.com/a/78661136/6426328
